# how can I test if Adobe AIR is installed using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, air

Is it possible to find with jQuery if Adobe AIR is installed?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd want to use jQuery to test this, but there are instructions for doing it with a .swf file and vanilla javascript here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e15.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7c85

You just need to replace

```
trace("Not installed."); 
// Take appropriate actions. For instance, present the user with 
// an option to install the application.
```

with the logic you want to fire when Air is not installed, so

```
$("#error").text("Please install Adobe Air to continue");
```

or something similar.

Is there any requirement to specifically test this with jQuery?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Reu, I saw that page before asking this question but I can't use Flash; I have to make it with jQUery.

Comment: @bobighorus Why can't you use flash?